# where is configure a SPJobDefinition

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, timer-jobs

I've to debug a job turning on sharepoint 2010 and i'd lik eto know where i can find when it's execute.
At which time? 
i suspect it runs 2 time by day so it should run only one

Thanks for your help

Comment: what you mean by Job turning? are these OOTB timer job or any custom timer job you developed? could you please name the timer job, which you want debug?

Answer (score 0):

You can check timer job history to check execution time of your timer job.

Go to central Admin -> Click on "Monitoring" -> Click on "Check Job Status"

Here you can find history of all timer jobs in your SP environment. You can edit timer job definition.

To debug, attach your code to "OWSTIMER.EXE" process.